# Can we set the summary and details tags so that the details appear ABOVE the summary (rather than below)?

Tags: html, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

By default in `HTML5`, when the user hits the summary box, the details are shown *below* the summary box. Is it possible to reverse the order, so that the details are shown *above* the summary?

Similarly, is is possible for the details to appear *to the left or to the right* of the summary box?

Comment: This is absolutely possible. Are you familiar with CSS?

Comment: which summary box? what details? Flex and flex-order spring to mind